# Is there research on performance penalties for types/constraints in Perl 6?

Tags: performance, raku

In contrast with Perl 5, Perl 6 introduced optional typing, as well as constraints, e.g.:

```
# Perl 5
sub mySub {
   my $probability = $_[0];
   # Do stuff with $probability
}

# Perl 6 - using optional typing and constraints
sub mySub(Real $probability where 0 < * < 1) {
   # Do stuff with $probability
}
```

Have there been studies that investigate whether there are performance penalties, and how large are they on different Perl 6 VMs, when using these capabilities?

I'm looking for something well designed, and cross-VM.

Comment: Related: [Talk by lizmat about speeding up Perl 6 from FOSDEM 2017](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/fosdem/2017/K.4.201/faaaaster.mp4). I think there was something in there that relates to your question. But even if not, you will probably enjoy watching it. :) There was also a talk by Nine about doing web development with Perl 6 where he had a lot of speed comparisons between Dancer and Mojo in Perl 5 and a port in Perl 6 and using his Perl 5 in Perl 6 stuff to get it to run, and I think that also talked about types, but the video is not up yet.

Comment: I have yet to see the obsession with typing that is built into Java and C++ pay any benefits. Do you have reason to believe that anything like the subroutine prototyping that you describe is worthwhile? If nothing else, if a policy to write code like that is enforced, then source files will become much bigger, substantially more noisy, and so less readable.

Comment: @Borodin: It means that if you make a mistake and pass an unacceptable kind of value to the subroutine, it'll die early with a helpful error message (in some cases even at compile time), rather than crashing & burning in a hard to understand fashion at a later point during the execution of the program, or worse, producing incorrect/corrupted data.

Comment: @DVK: I don't know of such a thorough performance study (and it would be a moving target, as Rakudo is becoming more optimized every month). But as a rule of thumb, `where` clauses and `subset` types always hurt performance because they're treated as opaque code that has to run every time the type is checked, whereas declarative type constraints can actually **improve** performance in some cases because they give additional info to the optimizer/specializer.

Comment: @smls: I know exactly what it means, but I have yet to see it pay any benefits. It's an 80s idea that strict typing was of any use, and now it's a fable. Java and C++ are also famous for requiring massive amounts of boilerplate before you can even start coding, so we're paying enormously in programmer time just to get stuff past the compiler when it's the compiler and run time system that should be serving *us*.

Comment: @Borodin - that sort of arguments might be better placed as a Q&A on Software Engineering.SE :)

Comment: @DVK: I'm not asking a question; I'm commenting on yours. In my opinion, such measures are more costly than they are worth.

Comment: @Borodin Based on what you've said here you seem to have the same perspective as Larry Wall, the lead designer for all the Perls, including Perl 6. There's a deep reason why Perls 1 thru 6 are extremely focused on keeping everything as weakly typed as they possibly can be. @ DVK's example and the stated concern about speed reflects a lack of understanding of Perl 6 types, which is fair enough -- that's why they've asked a question on SO. I hope to have time to write an answer tomorrow but it's essentially what @ smls has said. While you two may think you are disagreeing I think you may not be.

Comment: @Borodin - if you mean costly as far as wetware costs (not performance), there are plausible arguments either way, depending on specific situation. Which is why I suggested a post on Programmer's SE to illuminate the various arguments pro and contra.

Answer (score 5):

The most complete and *well designed* performance measurement work for Perl 6 is https://github.com/japhb/perl6-bench but it does not focus on the relative performance of optional typing. It does however have support for multiple VM backends so it might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

This answer aims to complement @donaldh's answer though I also don't know of any research specific to Perl 6 types / type constraints.

## Static type checking is fast

In the following the compiler does a `Complex ~~ Real` type check *at compile time*:

```
sub mySub(Real $probability where 0 < * < 1) {
    # Do stuff with $probability
}

my Complex \number = 1-2e3i;

mySub number;
```

Compiling the above code the Rakudo compiler realizes that `number` is `Complex` -- so you get a *compile time* type check failure:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling

Calling mySub(Complex) will never work with declared signature (Real $probability)
```

Over time Perl 6 compilers like Rakudo can improve their compile time code analysis leading to more type checking happening at compile time like the above.

Note that the `where` clause wasn't even tried. There's zero penalty for merely *specifying* `where` clauses. Any overhead due to `where` clauses only applies if a variable/value gets past the basic type checks.

## Most dynamic type checking is fast too

In the following the compiler does a `Complex ~~ Real` type check at *run time*:

```
multi sub mySub(Real $probability where 0 < * < 1) {
    # Do stuff with $probability
}

multi sub mySub(Complex $probability) {
    # Do stuff with $probability
}

my \number = 1-2e3i;

mySub number;
```

Compiling the above code the Rakudo compiler does *not* currently realize that `number` is `Complex` at compile time. At run time it considers and rejects the first `multi sub` declaration. As before it doesn't even try the `where` clause. Instead it makes a successful call to the second `multi sub` instead.

The examples thus far should make it clear that there's either zero or nearly zero run time performance penalty for most type checking.

## Native types

In theory, native types may be used for better performance:

```
sub foo-Int (Int $a) { my Int $b; $b++ for ^$a }
sub foo-int (int $a) { my int $b; $b++ for ^$a }

my $time;
$time = now; foo-Int my Int $ = 1e6.Int; say now - $time; # 1.0597491
$time = now; foo-int my int $ = 1e6.Int; say now - $time; # 0.7627174
```

In practice, specifying a native type will sometimes slow code down.

As Rakudo's optimization improves, the `int` optimization relative to `Int` should become more consistent and more significant. A similar story applies for other native scalar types and for native arrays.

## Coercion types

Perl 6 supports "coercion types".

For example, `Str(Int)` accepts any `Int` or a subtype thereof and coerces to a `Str`.

If the inner type of a coercion type matches, then the compiler will also incur the run-time overhead of running the coercion code.

## `where` clauses

After completing conventional static and dynamic type checking as described above, any applicable `where` clauses are invoked until one of them succeeds or all of them fail.

A compiler is free to analyze `where` clauses and realize they are equivalent to a sufficiently simple static type expression (eg `where Int | Str`) and use this info to avoid the run time overhead that comes from running arbitrary code. (cf. [@Larry's speculation about related matters](http://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Multiple_constraints).)

The current Rakudo does not analyze `where` clauses. In fact, it invokes `where` clauses more often than it strictly needs to.

## Compilers

Performance is a function of particular compilers/backends.

The primary Perl 6 compiler of note as 2017 began was Rakudo/MoarVM. There have been other compilers in the past that compiled significant subsets of Perl 6 and [there surely will be again](https://twitter.com/agentzh/status/826922812099043328); these may provide additional data.

## “Optional Typing” vs “Gradual Typing”

> Perl 6 introduced optional typing

In case you decide to search around the net for related data...

Perl 6 supports features like class-based inheritance and multi dispatch. Both of these technically disqualify Perl 6 from having an “Optional Typing” system according to wikipedia's [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Optional_type_systems).

Wikipedia instead places Perl 6 in the broad category [“Gradual Typing”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing) and so does Larry Wall and doc.perl6.org.

Comment: Please note that not specifying a type is the same as specifying Any as a type (generally).  So you're type checking your value against Any in that case.  Not specifying a type does not mean Rakudo doesn't to type checking: it does that all the time.  So there is no performance penalty in specifying basic types.  Subtypes may introduce a performance penalty if they cannot be resolved at compile time (like a where clause)

Comment: Out of curiosity if the expression of a where clause and a subtype is identical is there any matching of these two things being the same? So 0 < * <= 1 for probability if you had a subtype specified the same way from Real, would dispatch be faster without the need for the where check?

Comment: @MattOates Are you asking if a *user code refactor* from a *direct* `where` clause (one that's on the right of a parameter) to an *indirect* one via a subset type (one that's on the left of a variable/parameter) can improve run-time performance? If so, aiui, no. My current interpretation of [Larry's speculation](https://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Types_and_Subtypes) is that a compiler could reasonably spot at compile time that a `where` expression will evaluate to a named static type. [I wonder about interplay with multi candidate sorting semantics](https://glot.io/snippets/en3w0h08po).

Comment: @raiph I mean specifically in say multi dispatch if one of the requirements is a where clause but the type being passed is a subtype with an identical where clause has or more specifically *could* the compiler have already statically understood that these are identical and shimmed in a rule for the subtype also dispatching to the same method. Ultimately you will know what a where clause is compiling to in the AST if they are identical then you know the subtype is explicitly the same as a constraint elsewhere and could match it without having to evaluate the check at the point of dispatch.

Comment: @MattOates I've completely rewritten my answer yet again. I think what you're asking lands in the same ballpark as [@Larry's speculation about related matters](http://design.perl6.org/S12.html#Multiple_constraints), as mentioned in my rewrite.