# Does Perl 6 have an infinite Int?

Tags: raku

I had a task where I wanted to find the closest string to a target (so, edit distance) without generating them all at the same time. I figured I'd use the high water mark technique (low, I guess) while initializing the closest edit distance to `Inf` so that any edit distance is closer:

```
use Text::Levenshtein;

my @strings = < Amelia Fred Barney Gilligan >;

for @strings {
    put "$_ is closest so far: { longest( 'Camelia', $_ ) }";
    }

sub longest ( Str:D $target, Str:D $string ) {
    state Int $closest-so-far = Inf;
    state Str:D $closest-string = '';

    if distance( $target, $string ) < $closest-so-far {
        $closest-so-far = $string.chars;
        $closest-string = $string;
        return True;
        }

    return False;
    }
```

However, `Inf` is a [Num](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Num) so I can't do that:

> Type check failed in assignment to $closest-so-far; expected Int but got Num (Inf)

I could make the constraint a `Num` and coerce to that:

```
    state Num $closest-so-far = Inf;
    ...
        $closest-so-far = $string.chars.Num;
```

However, this seems quite unnatural. And, since `Num` and `Int` aren't related, I can't have a constraint like `Int(Num)`. I only really care about this for the first value. It's easy to set that to something sufficiently high (such as the length of the longest string), but I wanted something more pure.

Is there something I'm missing? I would have thought that any numbery thing could have a special value that was greater (or less than) all the other values. Polymorphism and all that.

Comment: what about `Real`, a role done by both `Int` and `Num`?

Comment: But a Real isn't an Int, and that's what I want to put into something that should only a whole number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*{new intro that's hopefully better than the unhelpful/misleading original one}*

@CarlMäsak, in [a comment he wrote below this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258965/does-perl-6-have-an-infinite-int#comment83317513_45261924) after my first version of it:

> Last time [I talked to Larry about this {in 2014}](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2014-08-20#i_9217249), his rationale seemed to be that ... Inf should work for all of Int, Num and Str

(The first version of my answer began with a "recollection" that I've concluded was at least unhelpful and plausibly an entirely false memory.)

In my research in response to Carl's comment, I did find one related gem in [#perl6-dev in 2016](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6-dev/2016-05-21#i_12521585) when Larry wrote:

> then our policy could be, if you want an Int that supports ±Inf and NaN, use Rat instead
>
> in other words, don't make Rat consistent with Int, make it consistent with Num

Larry wrote this post `6.c`. I don't recall seeing anything like it discussed [for `6.d`](https://github.com/perl6/6.d-prep).

*{and now back to the rest of my first answer}*

---

`Num` in P6 implements the IEEE 754 floating point number type. Per the IEEE spec this type *must* support several concrete values that are reserved to stand in for abstract concepts, including the concept of positive infinity. P6 binds the corresponding concrete value to the term `Inf`.

Given that this concrete value denoting infinity already existed, it became a language wide *general purpose* concrete value denoting infinity for cases that don't involve floating point numbers such as conveying infinity in string and list functions.

---

The solution to your problem that I propose below is to use a `where` clause via a `subset`.

A [`where` clause](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry-where_clause_%28Signature%29) allows one to specify run-time assignment/binding "typechecks". I quote "typecheck" because it's the most powerful form of check possible -- it's *[computationally universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)* and literally checks the actual *run-time value* (rather than a statically typed view of what that value can be). This means they're [slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117027/is-there-research-on-performance-penalties-for-types-constraints-in-perl-6) and run-time, not compile-time, but it also makes them *way* more powerful (not to mention way easier to express) than even [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) which are a relatively cutting edge feature that those who are into advanced statically type-checked languages tend to claim as only available in their own world<sup>1</sup> and which are intended to "prevent bugs by allowing extremely expressive types" (but good luck with figuring out how to express them... ;)).

A [subset declaration](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-subset-subset) can include a `where` clause. This allows you to *name* the check and use it as a named type constraint.

So, you can use these two features to get what you want:

```
subset Int-or-Inf where Int:D | Inf;
```

Now just use that `subset` as a type:

```
my Int-or-Inf $foo; # ($foo contains `Int-or-Inf` type object) 
$foo = 99999999999; # works
$foo = Inf;         # works
$foo = Int-or-Inf;  # works
$foo = Int;         # typecheck failure
$foo = 'a';         # typecheck failure
```

<sup>1</sup>. See [Does Perl 6 support dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947616/does-perl6-support-dependent-types) and [it seems the rough consensus is no](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dependent_type&oldid=740493581).

Comment: Although that might be Larry's rationale, Infinity is an abstract concept, so it's not quite a Num either. But, a junction of types seems very interesting.

Comment: [Last time](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2014-08-20#i_9217249) I talked to Larry about this, his rationale seemed to be that Inf should be that Inf should work for all of Int, Num and Str, and that how to do that is a secondary concern. @raiph, do you have a link to back up a newer stance than that?

Comment: brian-d-foy @CarlMäsak I've searched high and low and pondered the exchange Carl has linked and some others I found. I haven't asked Larry directly but I now suspect my recollection of his rationale was false. I've edited my answer accordingly.